# How do I set the Cordova serve script to use http instead of https?

Tags: cordova

My App dynamically loads content via a http connection. By default cordova uses https when I call `cordova-serve-android`. Unfortunately, my logging suggests that there's an error happening and pages loaded via https are not allowed to reload content via http. Is there a way to configure cordova to use http for the serve script?

Comment: Hi, I m really not sure that cordova uses https on cordova serve. As for as I know, it uses http by default. Why dont you try using browser platform to access the application in browser?

Comment: @Gandhi : The app can be build in different ways and some functions are tied to it being deployed as cordova.

Comment: Got it Christian. you mean to with browser platform you will not be able to test your functionality? i feel browser platform is more sophisticated way of testing than cordova serve.

Comment: @Gandhi Functionality such as cordova plugins feel to me not to be testable with the browser platform.

Comment: Not the case with all plugins. Many plugins do support browser platform. Reference link - https://www.raymondcamden.com/2016/03/22/the-cordova-browser-platform